# win32 c++ handle button press, PeekMessage not working?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, button, callback

I want to handle a c++ win32 API button press in a native window, I'm currently attempting doing it like so -

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <crtdefs.h>

#include <stdafx.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "name.h"
#include "libobs/obs.h"
#include "libobs/obs-module.h"

#define uploadName "Upload Window"
#define uploadWNDWidth 500
#define uploadWNDHeight 500
#define IDC_SELECT_VIDEO (100)

HWND  hBtnParent = HWND("UploadVideo");
HWND SelectVideoBTN, UploadBTN, hWnd, hBtn;

WPARAM wmId, wmEvent;

HINSTANCE hUpload;

WNDCLASSEX wcexUpload;

int nCmdShowUpload = 1;

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
//load obs modules
class load{
public:
    void static loading(){
        obs_module_load;
        obs_module_load_locale;
    }
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case BM_CLICK:
        if (wParam == IDC_SELECT_VIDEO) {
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"if", L"if", 0);
        }
        else{
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"else", L"else", 0);
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

bool obs_module_load(void)
{
    //init handler
    //HANDLE messageLoopThreadHandler;

    //set the handler to the thread
    //messageLoopThreadHandler = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(0, 0, &messageLoopThread, 0, 0, 0);

    //wait for object to be in specified state
    //WaitForSingleObject(messageLoopThreadHandler, INFINITE);

    //startMessageThreadLoop ThreadLoopInstance;

    //ThreadLoopInstance.startMyThread();

    MessageBox(hWnd, L"ThreadStart", L"ThreadStart", 0);
    //create message loop for buttons

    //cleanup thread created by _beginThreadEx
    //CloseHandle(messageLoopThreadHandler);

    WNDCLASSEX vidUploader;

    vidUploader.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    vidUploader.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    vidUploader.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    vidUploader.cbClsExtra = 0;
    vidUploader.cbWndExtra = 0;
    vidUploader.hInstance = hUpload;
    vidUploader.hIcon = LoadIcon(hUpload, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_P2GOVIDEOUPLOADER20));
    vidUploader.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    vidUploader.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    vidUploader.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_P2GOVIDEOUPLOADER20);
    vidUploader.lpszClassName = (LPCWSTR)(L"UploadVideo");
    vidUploader.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcexUpload.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    RegisterClassEx(&vidUploader);

    hInst = hUpload; // Store instance handle in our global variable

    // The parameters to CreateWindow explained:
    // szWindowClass: the name of the application
    // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar
    // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create
    // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)
    // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)
    // NULL: the parent of this window
    // NULL: this application dows not have a menu bar
    // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain
    // NULL: not used in this application
    hWnd = CreateWindow((LPCWSTR)(L"UploadVideo"), (LPCWSTR)(L"Upload Video's"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 100, NULL, NULL, hUpload, NULL);

    SelectVideoBTN = CreateWindow(
        L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
        L"Select Video's",      // Button text 
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
        10,         // x position 
        460,        // y position 
        100,        // Button width
        25,         // Button height
        hWnd,       // Parent window
        (HMENU)IDC_SELECT_VIDEO, // Assign appropriate control ID
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL);      // Pointer not needed.

    UploadBTN = CreateWindow(
        L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
        L"Upload",      // Button text 
        WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
        390,         // x position 
        460,         // y position 
        100,        // Button width
        25,        // Button height
        hWnd,     // Parent window
        NULL,       // No menu.
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL);      // Pointer not needed.

    RECT rect = { 0, 0, uploadWNDWidth, uploadWNDHeight };
    AdjustWindowRect(&rect, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE), FALSE);
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, 0, 0, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"), _T("Win32 Guided Tour"), NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    MSG msge = { 0 };
    while (PeekMessage(&msge, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0)
    {
        //translate and send messages
        TranslateMessage(&msge);
        DispatchMessage(&msge);
    }

    MSG msg;

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    //nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShowUpload);

    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    load::loading();

    return true;
}
```

When I currently load OBS, after having included the dll what happens is -

OBS starts
Window pops u
I click on window
Nothing happens
where on step 4, right after clicking on the button a MessageBox should popup saying - MessageBox(hWnd, L"else", L"else", 0); if it goes into the else, and if the if statement is true then MessageBox(hWnd, L"if", L"if", 0);

However my code won't even enter the callback function.

edit -

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        load::loading();
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is where the `WndProc` references refer to.

Comment: From the docs for `PeekMessage`: *If a message is available, the return value is nonzero.
If no messages are available, the return value is zero.* Why are you testing for positive return values? Further, why are you using `PeekMessage` instead of `GetMessage`? Why does your code have no error checking?

Comment: This is wrong: `HWND  hBtnParent = HWND("UploadVideo")`  because `HWND` is a window handle. Try a tutorial or at least have a look at this example [winapi walk through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx). Also Visual Studio has an option to create a simple c++ win32 program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm trying to get a basic example working & i'm using PeekMessage instead of GetMessage because GetMessage hangs the program, and PeekMessage doesn't

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I need to compile it to a dll, and it can't be a simple c++ win32 program

Comment: Giving up on `GetMessage` is the wrong solution. You need to fix the real problem. Ignoring the compiler warnings that you aren't returning a value from your window proc would be an improvement. Go back to `GetMessage` and fix the problem. Don't just make stuff up and guess. Start with an basic program that works and take small steps.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan creating a while look for GetMessage would cause the main-program to hang, I'm creating a plugin that's loaded by a different program, if I use a While loop with Get Message it won't ever leave it, and the main-program won't start up.

Comment: @Gerwin you don't seem to understand GUI programs? 'if I use a While loop with Get Message it won't ever leave it' - that's the idea, yes.

Comment: @MartinJames ofcourse that's the idea, but DavidHeffernan wants to press a never-ending-while-loop on me, when it's clearly the wrong choice.

Comment: No, it's the right choice. You code is full of mistakes, but if you feel you know better than we do, that's fine. I'll leave you in peace. On the other hand, if you want to listen and learn, we can teach you what you don't understand.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand that my code is full of mistakes, I'm still learning, but I've tried using a while loop, and it did hang the program, I would like to learn & am listenning.

Comment: No you are not. You have told us that `GetMessage` is wrong. That tells me that you are not listening. The big issue is your window procedure. What is `WndProc`? We cannot see that. Then you need to use `GetMessage`. You need to make sure you always return from your window procedure. And there are other problems, but let's start there.

Comment: From my experience GetMessage seems wrong, as it hangs the program, because it's a while loop, it won't ever leave it, unless used in a different thread

Comment: Fine, you know better. Carry using `PeekMessage` then.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I never said that I know better, I said from MY EXPERIENCE, there's a difference between saying that 'I know better' and 'from my experience' my experience could be incorrect.

Comment: Never mind, this isn't productive

Comment: I'd like to learn, could you explain to me why GetMessage is better according to your experience / expertise? - I'll try to switch to GetMessage if I can find out how to, without hanging the program

Comment: Why not read the documentation? The information can be found there. The point is that `GetMessage` blocks when the message queue is empty, allowing the processor to idle. With `PeekMessage` you have a busy loop. You really need to listen to advice and not reject it out of hand. We do know what we are talking about. We still have no idea what `WndProc` is.

Comment: When I created the project the basic WndProc functions were created along with it @DavidHeffernan I know that you know what you're talking about, but do you believe me if I say that I've been given incorrect information from other people (not on SO) multiple times  that that's the reason why I'm a bit skeptical?

Comment: We still, despite asking over and over again, have no idea what `WndProc` is. You refer to it in your code. It is the window procedure of your window class. But you don't reproduce its implementation. So, what is `WndProc`?

Comment: It's the windows procedure I'm trying to call ;p

Comment: You don't listen at all. Read my comment again. How can we possibly know what is in `WndProc` if you keep its contents hidden. I think I'm going to give up because you are just about impossible to help. You aren't going to learn if you don't listen.

Comment: I've added the WndProc code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've fixed my code - issue, thank you for the help ^^ thanks to you I've found where my issue originated from, during the creation of my window, my window was listenning to the incorrect Windows Procedure

Answer (score 2):

You're handling the receive of the [button click](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775941(v=vs.85).aspx#handling_button_messages) incorrect. You should handle a WM_COMMAND message and check the high word of the WPARAM for the notification code.

Comment: I've tried checking WPARAM before, I haven't tried checking for the HighWord, I have tried switch 
case WM_COMMAND:
if (LOWORD(wParam) == WORD(SelectVideoBTN)) {

Comment: Please see the documentation in the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GetMessage`, it won't hang the program.

You can use `PeekMessage` if you want constant update. For example in a game where you need to constantly paint the window. It has to be something like this:

```
//create window...
//show window...

MSG msg = { 0 };
while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
    //default message processing
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else 
    { 
        //constantly paint the window when there is no other message
        render_window(hwnd);
    }
}

//do cleanup here

return 0;
```

Note that the program terminates when the above `while` loop is finished. You cannot put `ShowWindow`/`UpdateWindow` after that.

Second, your main window seems to be `vidUploader`. And the window procedure for it is set to `vidUploader.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;` But you have not defined `WndProc`. Instead you have something else called `WindowProcedure`

To check for button notification:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_SELECT_VIDEO) 
        MessageBox...;
    break;
```